# Tried rotoscoping, Did it for 13 hours and the mask is scrambled on all frames

Tags: keyframes, masking, movie-clip-editor

[image]

I have been trying to mask. this is my first time masking in blender. I have set the mask to outline the chair and any movement.

I have made two masks but the mask in the video is mask 001 i didnt know how to delete the second one. i went to play the video back and well it was very laggy like the video wasnt really loading smoothly but the audio was running smoothly.

Anyway, I scrolled back and all this is scrambled up. i dont know what caused it. sometimes i would hit like V or F or H or maybe even T  when i meant to press G to move the points. but Im pretty sure i ctrl z'd it. I have saved the file and i dont know if i can get it back before it messed up.

If i have to redo all of it is there another way to speed this up or achieve this. I havent messed with any other stuff. I would right click on some handles to aligned single.

Im not sure what to do and Im getting discouraged.

Edit: wait i added point/anchors later could that be the thing that it is messing up? Like going backward to 5 points when later I add 10 points could it be trying to include the points made after?